# What do you call these words?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to figure out what the term is that describes words that look like this:

> やっぱり；　さっぱり；　うっかり；　こっそり；　ひっそり；　ぐっすり；　すっきり

They seem similar to 擬態語、義質語、and　擬音語, but I think they have a separate classification...

Is there a term that describes words like this? (Please let me know if this has already been asked). If there is not a term, how would one talk about these adverbs in Japanese? If I needed to state that "I have problems remembering (these types) of adverbs", how would one go about explaining that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called adverbs. Among them, やっぱり and うっかり are called sentential adverbs, and are independent of the core event described by the predicate. さっぱり, ひっそり, ぐっすり, and すっきり are called manner adverbs, and are directly tied to the core event described by the predicate. I am not sure which group こっそり belongs to.

Comment: I think Chris is looking for a word like "onomatopoeia" or "psychomimesis" rather than asking what part of speech they are.

Comment: @Matt I don't think they are onomatopoeia. At least, not all of them.

Comment: Right, I'm not sure that "onomatopoeia" is the right word either. But I think the shared morphophonemic characteristics (gemination, ending in -ri, possibly relatable to onomatopoeic or otherwise mimetic roots?) are what is of interest, not the fact that they are adverbs.

Comment: I agree that there is probably no better name to refer to the words listed in the question collectively other than saying “adverbs consisting of four morae whose second mora is っ and last mora is り.”

Comment: Are you sure about your comment that り in やはり comes from a verb ending?  Kanji 矢張り is an 当て字 and does not reflect the origin of the word.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Looks like you are right. I will remove that comment and add another one without that part. Matt, Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Matt If "gemination + -ri" is an affix that creates an adverb, then there is nothing more to these groups of words other than the fact that they are adverbs created by this affix.

Comment: @Sawa: Is there any way to speak in Japanese about these adverbs? Foreigners have often called them っ＋り adverbs or "びっくり" adverbs (for whatever reason).

Comment: @Chris I am not aware of a specific term for these. Sentential adverb is [文]{ぶん}[副]{ふく}[詞]{し} and manner adverb is [様]{よう}[態]{たい}副詞.

Comment: @Sawa: Ok, that helps a little more :)