# Is 翻す a former compound verb that merged into its current form?

Tags: etymology, compounds

The verb ひるがえす feels like it is made of two part ひる and かえす but I could not find any references backing this interpretation. And I can't figure out what would be ひる.

@snailboat also mentioned くつがえす whose meaning is very close to ひるがえす. If an answer could solve both cases it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you could ask the same thing about 覆す.

Comment: @snailboat I did not know that verb, but indeed if an answer could address them both it would be very interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[翻]{ひるがえ}す is a transitive verb of [翻]{ひるがえ}る.
It seems that it shows the movement of a flag originally.

This theory remains a matter of speculation.

> 翻る…[旗]{はた}が翻る(A flag flaps)
>   　→ひらひらと[裏]{うら}[返]{がえ}る→ひるがえる

others:

> [蘇]{よみがえ}る…[死者]{ししゃ}が蘇る(The dead revive)
>   　→[黄泉]{よみ}から[帰]{かえ}る→よみがえる

※黄泉 is the land of the dead.

I did not understand about [覆]{くつがえ}る...

(about a hypothesis)
This is an ancient Japanese poem([和歌]{わか})
たみのなけきに　むかつひめ　いそききしいに　ゆきひらき
民の嘆きに　向津姫　急ぎ紀志伊に　行き翻らき
[link](http://gejirin.com/gsrc/hi/hiraku.html)

Comment: Oh, I never made the parallel between 黄泉 and 蘇る! On the other hand, I can't really understand how ひらひらと裏返る could become 翻る, would it mean that the ら in ひらひら becomes somehow a る to  finally get to ひ*る*がえる?

Comment: Because they are similar. 
It seems that there is a hypothesis that '翻らき' was pronounced 'hiraki'.

Answer (score 3):

### ひるがえす・ひるがえる

Nariuji's answer above for 翻す matches what I've researched in the past.  ひる, ひら, even ふる (as in 振る) all seem to be related to ideas of *something flat waving or flapping*, cognate with 鰭{ひれ} *fin*, and possibly even cognate with 簸{ひ}る (ancient root verb ふ) *to winnow (by shaking grain)*.

### くつがえす・くつがえる

Looking specifically at 覆す・覆る, this appears to be a compound of くつ + かえす・かえる.

#### The かえす・かえる Part

One of the first senses listed for かえす, spelled using the kanji 反 or 返, is:

> 事物{ものごと}や事柄{ことがら}の位置{いち}を逆{ぎゃく}にする。
>   To reverse the positions of things or facts.

かえる is simply the intransitive side of this same meaning:

> 事物{ものごと}や事柄{ことがら}の位置{いち}が逆{ぎゃく}になる。
>   The positions of things or facts become reversed.

#### The くつ Part

But the くつ portion remains a bit mysterious.

- One etymon (root word) for くつ that seems to make sense semantically here is 靴 *shoes* -- as in 靴反す *to reverse the position of one's shoes* → *to make one's shoes on the top* → *to turn upside down*.
- As an alternative possibility, I note that くつ is also an old reading for 口, only used in very old compounds (such as 轡{くつわ} = 口 + 輪 = mouth ring = the bit for a horse).  So perhaps くつがえす = 口反す *to reverse the position of one's mouth* → *to make one's mouth on the bottom* → *to turn upside down*.

However, both options here refer specifically to a person's body, whereas 覆す・覆る can be used for all kinds of things.

**A more likely etymon** is probably the くつ in less-used adverb くっつり *sufficiently, adequately; completely*.  This word is missing from both [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A4%E3%82%8A) and [Weblio](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A4%E3%82%8A), but I do find it in my dead-tree 国語大辞典 from Shogakukan.  This may be the same くつ in くっつく *to really stick to something* (sometimes unsatisfyingly explained as 食う + 付く).

Many adverbs of the form `CVCCV + り`, such as くっつり or がっくり or ゆったり, appear to be derived from gemination (double-consonanting) of the underlying two-mora root + り from あり.  So ゆったり is from ゆた (with an underlying meaning of *loose* in terms of *roomy, not constricting*), observable in part by the synonymous adverb ゆたゆた, while がっくり is from がく (with an underlying meaning of *loose* in terms of *able to wiggle about*), with synonym がくがく.  (See [this related thread talking about such -り adverbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18729/%E3%81%A3-%E3%82%8A-form-adverbs/36660#36660).)

So くっつり would appear to derive from くつ (with an underlying meaning of *sufficiently; completely*).

#### Putting It Together

From this, くつ + かえす = くつ反{がえ}す = *to completely turn something over*, which seems to best match the meaning of 覆{くつがえ}す.  So too can we derive くつ + かえる = くつ反{がえ}る = *to completely turn over (on its own)*, which seems to best match the meaning of 覆{くつがえ}る.